# The script works on my computer but doesn't work when I upload it to the server

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the example code from GitHub to record video on a web page (https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record). The web page works completely on my computer. But when I upload the files to a server using FTP the web page shows the player but doesn't record when I click on the player.

I've tried changing the permissions on the FTP to allow read, write,  and execute but still doesn't work. The javascript and CSS files open when I click on them from the "view page source" code in the browser.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Audio/Video Example - Record Plugin for Video.js</title>

      <link href="video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="videojs.record.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="examples.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="video.min.js"></script>
      <script src="RecordRTC.js"></script>
      <script src="adapter.js"></script>

      <script src="videojs.record.min.js"></script>

      <script src="browser-workarounds.js"></script>

      <style>
      /* change player background color */
      #myVideo {
          background-color: #9ab87a;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <video id="myVideo" playsinline class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
      <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, or consider upgrading to     
        a
        web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
      supports HTML5 video.
        </a>
      </p>
    </video>

    <script>
    var options = {
        controls: true,
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        plugins: {
            record: {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                maxLength: 10,
                debug: true
            }
        }
    };

    // apply some workarounds for certain browsers
    applyVideoWorkaround();

    var player = videojs('myVideo', options, function() {
        // print version information at startup
        var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION +
            ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') +
            ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
        videojs.log(msg);
    });

    // error handling
    player.on('deviceError', function() {
        console.log('device error:', player.deviceErrorCode);
    });

    player.on('error', function(element, error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    // user clicked the record button and started recording
    player.on('startRecord', function() {
        console.log('started recording!');
    });

    // user completed recording and stream is available
    player.on('finishRecord', function() {
        // the blob object contains the recorded data that
        // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
        console.log('finished recording: ', player.recordedData);
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect to be able to record from the webcam after I click on the player. But it is only displaying the player and does not record when I click on the player. There is no error message.

Comment: Can you see if there are any errors in console log.

Comment: Do you provide proper permission for that page to use your camera?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess: on the local computer your origin is *http://localhost*. It's a secure context, due to the fact it's local. When you upload it to your server, it suddenly becomes *http://yourdomain.com*. This is **NOT** a secure context becuase it's not loaded over https. Try using [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to get an SSL cert and enable it to get a secure context. You **need* a secure context to get access to user's camera

Answer (score 0):

Does the website have https? Audio and video recording is problematic on Chrome on an insecure website. Firefox on the other hand works fine in this case.

If this is the case, I would recommend getting an ssl certificate, this is free through let's encrypt for example.